# Back button destroys activity in Crosswalk Android

Tags: android, webview, back

We are using the Crosswalk project to implement a web view in our Android application. As I can understand, Crosswalk will keep track if the application can go back on the website or not ([getNavigationHistory()](https://crosswalk-project.org/apis/embeddingapidocs_v2/org/xwalk/core/XWalkView.html#getNavigationHistory())) and if the user is at the root it will simply pause the activity when the user press the back-button one more time.

Scenario that works as it should:

1. User starts the app and sees the index
2. User press a link to go to another page
3. User goes to another link
4. User press the back-button on his phone and sees the page he saw on step #2
5. User press the back-button again to go back to the index
6. User press back again and now the application is paused

Continuing on the previous scenario but that will destroy the application:

7. User starts the application again (resume it)
8. User press the back button
9. The activity should be paused but is destroyed instead.

So I'm wondering if this is the standard behavior or is it a bug in Crosswalk?

I would like the app to go to pause every time the user press the back-button.

I've tried to override the standard back behavior but this still destroys the activity the second time back is pressed:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DebugFunctions.showToast(mThis, "onBackPressed");
    DebugFunctions.showLog(LOG_TAG, "onBackPressed");

    DebugFunctions.showLog(LOG_TAG, "mXWalkView: " + String.valueOf(mXWalkView != null) + ", canGoBack: " + String.valueOf(mXWalkView.getNavigationHistory().canGoBack()));

    if (mXWalkView != null && mXWalkView.getNavigationHistory().canGoBack()) {
        DebugFunctions.showLog(LOG_TAG, "First");
        mXWalkView.getNavigationHistory().navigate(XWalkNavigationHistory.Direction.BACKWARD, 1);
    } else {
        DebugFunctions.showLog(LOG_TAG, "Second");
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
}
```

Another observation is that the back button destroys the activity even if I have pressed a link (which Crosswalk should register) on the second time the application is started.

Comment: I have no experience with Crosswalk, but destroying activity when back button is pressed is standard android behavior. Cited from: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

    When the user presses the Back button, the current activity is popped from the top of the stack (the activity is destroyed) and the previous activity resumes (the previous state of its UI is restored).

Comment: But isn't it strange that on the first back-press the app is paused, and then on the second back-press I can't even navigate back in the app since it just closes the app entirely?

Comment: for me, the first page in the history stack of the Crosswalk web view was "about:blank". Navigating back to it created a blank/black screen which looked like the view was destroyed. But it wasn't it was just a legitimate blank page being displayed in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to go back in the xwalkview. It works well.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    //WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    XWalkView mXWalkView = (XWalkView) findViewById(R.id.xWalkView);
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:

                if (mXWalkView.getNavigationHistory().canGoBack()) {
                    mXWalkView.getNavigationHistory().navigate(XWalkNavigationHistory.Direction.BACKWARD, 1) ;
                } else {
                    finish();
                    if (MainActivity.mTencent.isSessionValid()) {
                        MainActivity.logout();
                    }
                }
                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```